# PowerShell - Unrestricted execution policy Issue

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-server-2008, code-signing-certificate

I have a windows update module which I copy over into the Module directory for PS. however, even with the Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted command issued, when i try to execute the .ps1 file, I get an error stating that the it's not digitally signed and will not run.

I was under the impression that if you set the exection policy to 'unrestricted' that you don't need to have scripts 'signed' in order to run.

Is there something else that I need to do in the Windows 2008 R2 environment?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you copying the *.ps1* file into the module directory -_[C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules]_ ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the script is not blocked. Check if the script's properties page contains an 'Unblock' button. If so, click it to unblock the file.